# recover a date and time in mongo db with moment js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, vuejs2, momentjs

when I get the date on mongodb, I get a date and time with 2 hours late, I would like to fix this problem by using js time by setting the time in french format, but I do not know how to do .

I work in javascript and in vue js

Comment: what is french format for datetime?

Comment: `var date = new Date(existingDate); date.setHours(date.getHours() + 2)` should do..